# How to Use Xamarin iOS library in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin.ios

I have Xamarin iOS library written in C#

I want use this library in swift

Is that possible?

Comment: No, it is not possible

Answer (score 0):

Isn’t possible. There is not way to recognize C# in swift projects, maybe you could trying to compile/transpile or some your library to swift or objetive-c first.